# Something missing with NLTK and tokenize

Tags: python, nltk, tokenize

this is a part of my code where I try to tokenize a greek paragraph.

```
doc = "Ο υπουργός Οικονομικών Γιάννης Στουρνάρας διαβίβασε την Τετάρτη στον πρόεδρο της αρμόδιας Αρχής κατά του ξεπλύµατος µαύρου χρήµατος, Παναγιώτη Νικολούδη, το αίτημα του υπουργού Υγείας Αδωνι Γεωργιάδη για κατά προτεραιότητα έλεγχο του «πόθεν έσχες» των διοικητών και υποδιοικητών που υπηρέτησαν στο Εθνικό Σύστημα Υγείας από το 2000 έως και σήμερα."

tokens = nltk.WordPunctTokenizer().tokenize(doc)
```

The result is missing of few words for example `"Αρχής"` or `"έσχες"`.

If I use this online tool for the same tokenize module, the words are still there.

[online tool](http://text-processing.com/demo/tokenize/)

What I have understant until now is that after this code, I have another line where I remove all words with < 3 characters.

And if I print the tokens, the word `"έσχες"` for example tokenized as `["έ","σχ","ες"]`. Why those words tokenized too? I thought that this module split sentences into the words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works when you `decode` your input to Unicode before passing it to NLTK. Assuming it's encoded as UTF-8:

```
>>> doc = doc.decode("utf-8")
>>> print(doc)
Ο υπουργός Οικονομικών Γιάννης Στουρνάρας διαβίβασε την Τετάρτη στον πρόεδρο της αρμόδιας Αρχής κατά του ξεπλύµατος µαύρου χρήµατος, Παναγιώτη Νικολούδη, το αίτημα του υπουργού Υγείας Αδωνι Γεωργιάδη για κατά προτεραιότητα έλεγχο του «πόθεν έσχες» των διοικητών και υποδιοικητών που υπηρέτησαν στο Εθνικό Σύστημα Υγείας από το 2000 έως και σήμερα.
>>> tokens = nltk.WordPunctTokenizer().tokenize(doc.decode("utf-8"))
>>> for t in tokens:
...     print(t, end=" ")
... print()
... 
Ο υπουργός Οικονομικών Γιάννης Στουρνάρας διαβίβασε την Τετάρτη στον πρόεδρο της αρμόδιας Αρχής κατά του ξεπλύµατος µαύρου χρήµατος , Παναγιώτη Νικολούδη , το αίτημα του υπουργού Υγείας Αδωνι Γεωργιάδη για κατά προτεραιότητα έλεγχο του « πόθεν έσχες » των διοικητών και υποδιοικητών που υπηρέτησαν στο Εθνικό Σύστημα Υγείας από το 2000 έως και σήμερα .
```

**EDIT**: Ok, do `decode("iso-8859-7")` instead.

Comment: I tried it but I have this error 

doc = doc.decode("utf-8")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xcf in position 0: invalid continuation byte

Comment: @Tasos: then it's not UTF-8, and you should figure out what encoding the data is in. Try dumping it in a file and running the `file` command on that.

Comment: Can you explain it more? I don't understand what you mean with this. A external url is ok too.

Comment: I find it. I paste it in a txt file and open it with google chrome. Then go to the encoding and iso-8859-7 was checked. Then I tried it on python code and it worked!

Comment: Can you edit your answer with the new encoding, so I can choose it as  the best answer?